# Problems running anything with elevated privileges in GUI

Tags: 14.04, privileges, policykit

This problem started today. I cannot run any programs with elevated privileges from the Unity GUI. I am in the sudo group, and all of this worked fine yesterday...Ubuntu 14.04

- Software Center immediately closes without offering the password
  dialog.
- User Manager does not allow me to unlock.
- I can no longer mount a USB stick, as I don't have permission.

I CAN execute `gksu synaptic` from the command line. And I can mount the USB manually with `sudo mount /dev/sdl1 /media/usb`

**UPDATE:**

I discovered this has to do with PolicyKit. I sort of solved the problem by creating `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-myauthority.conf` and specifically adding my username to `AdminIdentities`

That still doesn't explain why PolicyKit is not honoring the sudo group in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf`, as I've stated I'm in the sudo group.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same behaviour - adding the users to the authority list gives them access, but not the group.

In my case I had to reinstall the package `libpolkit-gobject-1-0`, which I somehow accidentially removed.

Seems that policykit needs that library to find out in which groups a user is.